# Android single fragment on backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have a main fragment (Fragment A) that is my app's home screen. I have a list of Fragments (Fragment B, Fragment C) that replace Fragment A when selected from a drawer. I want to keep the backstack at 1, so that no matter how many times the user navigates between B & C, the back button always takes them back to A. My Code so far works the first time the app is launched and Fragments B/C are visited.

However, after the user backs to Fragment A for the first time, any subsequent replacements leak Fragment A in the background (that is, Fragment B/C is overlapped ontop of Fragment A instead of fully replacing it.) At the same time, Fragment B/C (whichever was selected first, always becomes the "root fragment" so that when I press back, it stops at that Fragment then closes the App instead of going back to A.

I am stuck on what could be causing this behavior?

The code in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GoogleMapFragment fragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_main_container, fragment, fragment.TAG)
            .commit();
}

   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction txn = fm.beginTransaction();


        if (count > 0) {
            txn.replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
        else {
            txn.replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(backstateName)
                    .commit();

        }
}

onMyEventListener() {
....
  case MenuProfileFragment.SHOP:
            EmptyStoreFragment fragment1 = EmptyStoreFragment.newInstance();
            replaceFragment(fragment1); break;

  case MenuProfileFragment.TRANSACTIONS:
            OrderListsFragment fragment2 = OrderListsFragment.newInstance();
            replaceFragment(fragment2); break;
}
```